# Popup with a message - Google Scripts - Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In SpreadSheets, I would like to see a welcome message.
I would like to style this message, bold font etc.
I try this way, but it doesn't open.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>This interface was written in HTML!</p>');

ui.showModalDialog(html, "HTML!");
}

function alertMe() {
  
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You've been alerted!");
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work but your question is not very clear. Also are you calling the alertMe() function. I can see the function definition but not the function call.  If you want to format the message you can make a general purpose function e.g.

```
function showAlert(msg) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
}
```

Using the word "return" here makes no sense. You can use it later like below:

```
showAlert ("An error occurred. Please ...");
```

============ Answer update ==========
-- As per the discussion in comments. I noticed that the OP wanted to display a modal dialog on opening the spreadsheet after further research and reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script , I came up with the below solution.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("showStartupMsg")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onOpen()
    .create();
}


function showStyledMsg(msgHTML) {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msgHTML);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "HTML!");
}

function showStartupMsg() {
  showStyledMsg("<p>this is a <b>bold</b> test msg</b>");
}
```

The above code works for this purpose there is a slight delay in rendering the modal dialog's body but that cannot be helped.

Comment: Yes, but this text is without style (bold etc.) and I would like this.

Comment: The same logic would apply. Pass the html as a  param to the other function then.

E.g. define a function
```function showStyledMsg(msgHTML) {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msgHTML);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "HTML!");
}```
and then use it like ```showStyledMsg("<p>this is a <b>bold</b> test msg</p>")``` you can add more parameters to the function to control the modal dialog's width and height and other options. E.g. you can add a param to make the title customizable instead of "HTML!".

Comment: But when I used this:
```function showStyledMsg(msgHTML) { 
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msgHTML); 

  ui.showModalDialog(html, "HTML!"); 
  } 
  showStyledMsg("<p>this is a <b>bold</b> test msg</b>");```

Nothing happens. It does not open automatically when you open a sheet.

Comment: If you want a message to show on opening the sheet there is a special function called onOpen(). You will need to make a call to showStyledMsg() there. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers to see  documentation related to triggers and their and associated functions.

Comment: Yes, but it still not working

```function onOpen(){
  showStyledMsg("<p>this is a <b>bold</b> test msg</b>");
}

function showStyledMsg(msgHTML) {    
  
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();    
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msgHTML);     
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "HTML!");    
  }    
  ```

Comment: Actually your right it doesn't work. Maybe google does not allow dialogs on open. You can try adding a menu item and calling this function in a function there. Like as given in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Comment: I added an update to my answer I have tested the code and it works on my end.